# Buscar la última ocurrencia de un texto e insertar texto antes

Tags: c#, regex

Tengo varios textos con 2 `"Saludos,"`, con contenido en el medio que varía. Por ejemplo:

```
"Saludos,
 Mi nombre es Luca y estoy interesado en vuestra oferta de trabajo.

 Saludos,"
```

Quiero introducir un texto, por ejemplo `"10-01-2018"` en la línea anterior al segundo `"Saludos,"`. El resultado final que quiero lograr es este:

```
"Saludos,
 Mi nombre es Luca y estoy interesado en vuestra oferta de trabajo.
 10-01-2018
 Saludos,"
```

El problema es que encuentro 2 textos iguales y no sé cómo hacer para hacer que solo me añada líneas en el 2º texto.

---

Describo con más detalle lo que intento hacer y el código que tengo:

Estoy tratando de realizar la búsqueda de texto introducido por un control textbox en una serie archivos .txt , con el fin de realizar un "replace" y añadir más texto en la fila anterior. Todos los archivos de texto tienen el mismo formato (solo cambia el contenido de los nombres y poco más).

Para ello utilizo regex y busco en todos los ficheros el texto `"Saludos,"`.

Utilizo regex porque creo que necesito una expresión regular, que es lo que no sé como hacer, para obtener el segundo `"Saludos,"`. Mi idea es que si un día quiero que sea otro texto, lo pueda modificar.

Este es mi código para leer los archivos, buscar y reemplazar, y volver a escribir en el archivo:

```
//Obtengo el texto introducido por teclado
var mytext = txtDescript.Text.ToString();
//Cargo la lista de documentos
var ListDataDocuments= (List<MyDocument>)ListData.ItemsSource;

foreach (MyDocument Document in ListDataDocuments)
{
    string docText = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(document.FilePath))
    {
        //Leo el contenido del fichero
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    string replaceVariable =  mytext+"\n"+ "$&";
    string pattern = @"Saludos,";
    Regex regexText = new Regex(pattern);
    docText = regexText.Replace(docText, replaceVariable);

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(document.FilePath))
    {
        sw.Write(docText);
    }


public class MyDocument
{
    public String FilePath { get; set; }
    public String FileContent { get; set; }
}
```

En la variable `replaceVariable` guardo el texto por teclado nuevo (que será la fecha) +`"\n $&"` porque quiero introducir dicha fecha en la fila anterior a `"Saludos,"`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, me soluciono el problema a la perfeccion.

Comment: Luca, si la respueta te solucionó el problema, marcala con un check (a la izq , debajo de la puntuacion) para marcarla como Aceptada. Asi el resto de usuarios sabaran que esa respuesta da solucion al problema. Y además ganas algo de rep aceptandola :D . Recuerda tambien leer el [tour] para ver como funciona el sitio y ganar una medall. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es relevante en tu pregunta que estés leyendo de un TextBox o de un archivo. Básicamente tenés 3 strings: el texto original, el texto a buscar y el texto a insertar antes. Tenemos 2 formas:

**LastIndexOf e Insert**

Al ser un texto fijo, no hace falta complicarse con regex. Básicamente buscamos la última posición del texto buscado ([LastIndexOf](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_String_)), e insertamos el nuevo texto en la posición encontrada ([Insert](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Insert_System_Int32_System_String_)).

```
public static string insertarAntesDelUltimo(string texto,string buscar,string insertarAntes)
{
    int posicion = texto.LastIndexOf(buscar); //Última posición encontrada
    if ( posicion >= 0 ) //Se encontró?
    {
        texto = texto.Insert( posicion, insertarAntes); //Insertar el nuevo texto
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
docText = insertarAntesDelUltimo(docText, "Saludos,", mytext + "\n");
```

**Regex con RegexOptions.RightToLeft**

Para encontrar la última posición de un patrón, usamos la opción [RightToLeft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_RightToLeft).
Es importante escapar el texto ingresado por el usuario ([Escape](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.7.1)) para que tome al texto como literal, sin interpretar posibles metacaracteres con significado especial en el regex.

```
public static string insertarEnLineaAnterior( string texto, string buscar, string insertarAntes)
{
    //desde el inicio de la línea, el texto buscado (escapando metacaracteres!)
    string patron = @"\n?^(.*" + Regex.Escape(buscar) + ")";
    string reemplazo = insertarAntes.Replace("$","$$") + "\n$1";
    RegexOptions opc = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft;

    //creamos el regex y reemplazamos
    Regex regex = new Regex(patron, opc);
    return regex.Replace(texto, reemplazo, 1); //1 solo reemplazo (el último)
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
docText = insertarEnLineaAnterior(docText, "Saludos,", "10-01-2018");
```

Descripción del regex que se forma es:

```
\n?^(.*Saludos,)
```

- `\n?` - Salto de línea (opcional)
- `^` - Coincide con el inicio de la línea (porque estamos usando [RegexOptions.Multiline](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Multiline))
- `(.*Saludos,)` - Grupo 1:

  - `.*` - 0 o más caracteres (cualquier caracter, excepto saltos de línea)
  - `Saludos,` - Texto literal

Y lo reemplazamos por la fecha + un salto de línea (`\n`) + el texto capturado por el primer grupo (`$1`).